# Atom.core not found when in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, gdata

I'm trying to use the google for content api for shopping via the gdata client library and the atom library seems to be giving me an error.

This only happens when I try to run my code in a virtualenv.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tabakd/documents/programming/kek/server/merchant.py", line 2, in <module>
    import atom.data
  File "/home/tabakd/documents/programming/kek/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/data.py",       line 24, in <module>
    import atom.core
ImportError: No module named core
```

Thanks in advance for the help :D.

### SOLUTION:

As per someones advice on IRC I was able to fix this error by adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the beginning of `client.py` and `data.py` in the atom directory.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and accept it so it shows up as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per someones advice on IRC I was able to fix this error by adding from **future** import absolute_import to the beginning of client.py and data.py in the atom directory.